# SysML-Designer: block properties and associations between blocks not displayed

Tags: uml-designer

When I create a BDD or open a BDD from the AlarmRadio example no block properties and no associations between blocks are displayed:

[no properties shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5K1QR.png)

[no associations shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUutZ.png)

Configuration see below. Same behavior on a Win7-Machine.

The documentation doesn't seem to cover that topic. What do I have to do to correctly display properties and associations in bdd diagrams?

Windows 10
Java 1.8.0_121
UML Designer: 7.1.0.201611211359 Sirius 4.1/Neon Win64 downloaded from umldesigner.org/download/

SysML Designer 7.1.0.201611141124 installed in UML Designer using "Install UML Components"

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [mcve] so that we could help you better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a bug, you can fill an issue on the SysML Designer bug tracker:
https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/SysML-Designer/issues